# Issue Updating Snap Store on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: 23.10

Hello Ask Ubuntu community,

I'm currently running Ubuntu 23.10, and I've encountered an issue while trying to update the Snap Store. Here are the details of the problem:

Description:

The Ubuntu Software application notifies me that there is an update available for Snap.
When I go to Ubuntu Software and click on the update button for Snap, I receive an error message stating that"Unable to update "Snap Store": (null): cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (ubuntu-software), pids: 2098" .The exact error message is not displayed in the terminal.
Steps I've Tried:

I have closed the Ubuntu Software application and retried the update.
I attempted to manually update the Snap Store using the terminal with sudo snap refresh snap-store, but the issue persists.
System Information:

snap    2.60.4+23.10.1
snapd   2.60.4+23.10.1
series  16
ubuntu  23.10
kernel  6.5.0-13-generic

I would appreciate any assistance or insights into resolving this issue. Thank you!

Comment: "*The exact error message is **not** displayed in the terminal.*" Is that a typo? Else what is displayed?

Comment: @user535733 the message is displayed in a floating box in the ubuntu software application after clicking update on snap and entering password of the pc to update snap

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was an [issue over the past day](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-snap-store/40559/5?u=johnandmegh) where the previous version of the App Center / Snap Store got pushed out to 23.10 users.

This version is based on GNOME Software, which runs persistently in the background even after the visible application window is closed. To be able to refresh the Snap (and get back to the new App Center), open up your System Monitor app by pressing the <kbd>Super Key</kbd> (usually the left <kbd>Windows</kbd> key by defaut) and in the search box start to type `System Monitor` and select from the options provided. Under the `Processes` tab and in the search box type `gnome-software`, select it and click on `End Process` in the bottom left hand corner to kill that process.

You'll probably get a notification within a few seconds that snap-store has successfully refreshed, but if not, `sudo snap refresh` should confirm that all is now in order.

Comment: If that answers the question for you, please consider accepting it (the grey tick under the votes). This will help other users with finding a solution if they have the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Process Name
at-spi2-registryd gdm-wayland-session
gjs
gjs
Igjs
gnome-keyring-daemon
gnome-session-binary
gnome-session-binary
gnome-session-ctl
gnome-shell
gnome-shell-calendar-server
gnome-system-monitor
|xdg-desktop-portal-gnome. I could not find gnome-software

Comment: Try `snap-store`